# Resolve a custom implicit equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, implicit

Consider the following non-linear equation:

$$
k x = \frac{\frac{9}{4}-y^{22/25}}{2\ 2^{19/25} y^{22/25}-\frac{9}{4} \left(10 y+e^{-y}\right)^{22/25}-1}
$$

where `k` is a constant, i.e, $k=0.3516$, $y=y(x)$ and $y(0)=\log(2.25^{0.88}) \quad x \in [0,1]$

I want to solve the numerical solution of $y$.

My trail as shown below:

$$
\frac{d(k x)}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\frac{9}{4}-y^{22/25}}{2\ 2^{19/25} y^{22/25}-\frac{9}{4} \left(10 y+e^{-y}\right)^{22/25}-1}\right)
$$

```
rightHand = 
  D[(-y[x]^(22/25) + 9/4)/(-9/4*(10 y[x]/1 + E^(-y[x]))^(22/25) + (4*y[x])^(22/25) - 1), x] // Simplify;

leftHand = 0.3516;
sol = NDSolve[{leftHand == rightHand, y[0] == Log[2.25^0.88]}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

However, Mathematica gives the following error:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.5671511305713252`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I found a solution  by writting the equation as `y'[x]==newRightHandSide` using `eq = First@First@Solve[leftHand == rightHand, Derivative[1][y][x]] /. 
   Rule -> Equal;`

Comment: then  `sol = NDSolve[{eq, y[0] == Log[2.25^0.88]}, y, {x, 0, 1}]` but the solution has a strong slope as shown in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVcQt.png) . Is that expected ?

Comment: Also having used this method in systems of non linear equations this stiff message can occur at times. For the case of multiple non linear equations I usually used one of the options of NDSolve for stiff problems but I do not remember the name now. You can maybe check the documentation for stiff problems if that happens in the future.

Comment: @userrandrand Thanks, I notice that your solution still has the error `NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.5671511305713252, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>`

Comment: I did not receive any error

Comment: What version are you using ?

Comment: @userrandrand `Mathematica V10.4`, what version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 13.1 that might be the reason. I tried again after you told me that and I still did not receive any error.

Comment: I did not try your method. I see that I do not receive an error with your code

Comment: @userrandrand Your code and my solution generate the same graph in V13.1 (https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/febdc7ed-946c-45e3-b369-a29ef9b8e4bb)

Comment: `Solve[((-y[x]^(22/25) + 
       9/4)/(-9/
         4*(10 y[x]/1 + E^(-y[x]))^(22/25) + (4*y[x])^(22/25) - 1) /. 
    y[x] -> y) == 0, y]` finds a solution that seems different than your initial condition

Comment: Are you sure about your initial condition ? It is possible that there are multiple solutions and that yours might be good

Comment: (-y[x]^(22/25) + 
    9/4)/(-9/4*(10 y[x]/1 + E^(-y[x]))^(22/25) + (4*y[x])^(22/25) - 
    1) /. y[x] -> Log[2.25^0.88] is not small. I am not sure your initial condition is consistent with the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
f[y_] := (-y^(22/25) + 
    9/4)/(-9/4*(10 y/1 + E^(-y))^(22/25) + (4*y)^(22/25) - 1);

lst = Table[{kx, 
    FindRoot[f[y] == kx, {y, 0.1 + 2 kx}][[1, 2]]}, {kx, -0.07, 0.07, 
    0.001}] // Chop;
```

yielding

```
ListLinePlot[lst, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["y", 16, Italic], Style["kx", 16, Italic]}]
```

[image]

**Edit**:
There is a more direct way of resolving the plot by using a `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{(-y^(22/25) + 
     9/4)/(-9/4*(10 y/1 + E^(-y))^(22/25) + (4*y)^(22/25) - 1), 
  y}, {y, 0, 5}, AspectRatio -> 0.7, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["y", 16, Italic], Style["kx", 16, Italic]}]
```

[image]

In this sense, one can regard your equation as already resolved with respect to `kx` in the parametric form.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have a question with `{kx, -0.07, 0.07, 0.001}`. Because $x \in [0,1]$, $k x \in [0, k]$.

Comment: from the data in the ListPlot that is y as a function of kx no ? @Lavender looking at the plot  of kx as a function of y , one sees a plateau for y large which seems to infer that y as a function of kx, the reciprocal, diverges.Specifically, it seems to diverge around 0.07 which might be why that was chosen above.

Comment: @Lavender You just take those values that you are looking for. That's up to you. There is a more direct way of doing this. See the later edit.